# Radio button data not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm playing around with Form Helpers. I found some code from another SO question and thought it was pretty efficient at creating radio buttons with an elegant loop. Now that I've incorporated it, it doesn't save the data (e.g. the *category* value is not being saved to the *project* table)

Please see code below of *_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
      <label for="category">Category:</label>
      <% [ 'checklist', 'process'].each do |category| %>
      <br><%= radio_button_tag 'category', category, @category == category %>
      <%= category.humanize %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radio button parameter is being created outside of the `project` structure. If you look at `params`, you'll probably see

```
{:category => "your_category", :project => {...project params...}}
```

It is because you're using the `radio_button_tag` instead of the regular form helper. Try this instead:

```
f.radio_button :category, category, :checked => (@category == category)
```

Also, as Justin said, make sure `:category` is included in the `project_params` in your controller.

Comment: @orky Cool, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer (green checkmark to the left of the answer.)

Comment: Done! And thanks to your rep I'm now able to upvote you too :)